# Given a specific date, find the next date in the list using Python

Tags: python, list, datetime

I have a list of dates. And given a specific input date, want to find the next date in the list. Example is:

```
my_dates_list = ['2019-01-31', '2019-02-28', '2019-03-31', '2019-04-30', '2019-05-31', '2019-06-30'].
InputDate = '2019-03-31'
```

the output should be '2019-04-30' because it is the next date of the InputDate found in the list.

Another example: if InputDate is `'2019-03-31'`, the output should be `'2019-04-30'`.

Comment: Maybe sort the list by datetime and take 'Input + 1'? There might be a more pythonic approach out there

Comment: "pandas"? your code doesn't use it at all... Anyways you can probably just sort it and binary search

Comment: @SuperStormer What part of the rest of my code would be helpful for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joe's answer works, but because your dates are zfilled and are ordered year to day, you don't need a parser.  Here's a two-line solution.

```
my_dates_list = ['2019-01-31', '2019-07-13', '2019-02-28', '2019-03-31',
                 '2019-04-30', '2019-05-31', '2019-06-30']
input_date = '2019-03-31'

results = [d for d in sorted(my_dates_list) if d > input_date]
output = results[0] if results else None
print(output)
```

result = '2019-04-30'

Comment: or using a list comprehension, `result = [d for d in sorted(my_dates_list) if d > input_date][0]`

Comment: @MarkReed that's much more readable - edited to replace with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string data into datetime using `datetime.strptime`, then sort them in ascending order, then check if the value is greater than the input value. If you have a value, then you can return it using `datetime.strftime`. For more details on using datetime, please refer to this Stack Overflow thread [Converting Strings into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime). You can also see additional inputs in this link on [Converting between datetime and strings](https://jingwen-z.github.io/converting-between-datetime-and-string/)

Here's how I would do it:

```
from datetime import datetime
my_dates_list = ['2019-01-31', '2019-02-28', '2019-03-31', '2019-04-30', '2019-05-31', '2019-06-30']
my_sorted_dates = [datetime.strptime(i,'%Y-%m-%d') for i in my_dates_list]
my_sorted_dates.sort()

def find_next(x):
    y = [a for a in my_sorted_dates if a > datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d')]
    return y[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if y else None

print (find_next('2019-03-12'))

print (find_next('2019-03-31'))

print (find_next('2019-04-30'))

print (find_next('2019-08-30'))
```

Results will be:

```
2019-03-31 # for find_next('2019-03-12')

2019-04-30 # for find_next('2019-03-31')

2019-05-31 # for find_next('2019-04-30')

None # for find_next('2019-08-30')
```